# Updating WordPress across multiple versions

Tags: plugins, updates

I need to update WordPress from version 4.4.9 to 4.7.4 also there are 17 plug-ins that need to be updated as well. My question is should I update the plug-ins first, and then proceed to update WordPress or vice versa? I'm using this link as a guide: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_Extended#Upgrading_Across_Multiple_Versions

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the plugins which way will be better. I had a similar situation with this many plugins, but i had to update WordPress just from 4.7 to 4.7.3. My update order was:

1. WordPress
2. Theme
3. Plugins
4. Translations

If you are not sure, i think the best way is to copy your WordPress to a private server (for example you can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) on your local computer) and test the update process in there. If all works, it should work on your real instance as well.
Read [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) for more information on copying your WordPress instance.